# Brownian motion dyadic construction convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Say $B$ is a Brownian motion and $B^n$ is the function that is equal to $B$ at all numbers of the form $2^{-n}\mathbb{N}$ and linear on the intervals $[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}]$. I am trying to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\sup_{[0,1]}|B-B^n|\leq\epsilon )=1$. I was thinking that $|B-B^n|$ can be bounded by $|B_{\frac{k}{2^n}}-B_{\frac{k+1}{2^n}}|$ which is $\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{2^n})$ distributed. Is this correct? Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: So you have a Brownian motion $B$ before constructing it?

Comment: Indeed. The question itself is not about constructing it, though it is related. I edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the process $W_t^{n,k}:=(B_t-B_t^n)$, $t\in[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}]$ is a [Brownian bridge](https://www.randomservices.org/random/brown/Bridge.html). Therefore, using for example [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003964/brownian-bridges-level-reaching-probability),
\begin{align*}
&\mathsf{P}\!\left(\sup_{t\in [k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n}]}|W_t^{n,k}|>\epsilon\right) \\
&\qquad\le 2\mathsf{P}\!\left(\sup_{t\in [k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n}]}W_t^{n,k}>\epsilon\right)=2e^{-2^{n+1}\epsilon^2},
\end{align*}
and so,
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{P}\!\left(\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t-B_t^n|> \epsilon\right)&= \mathsf{P}\!\left(\max_{0\le k\le 2^n-1}\sup_{t\in [k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n}]}|W_t^{n,k}|> \epsilon\right) \\
&\le \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\sup_{t\in [k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n}]}|W_t^{n,k}|> \epsilon\right) \\
&\le 2^{n+1}e^{-2^{n+1}\epsilon^2}\to 0 \quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, was my idea that $|B_t-B^n_t|$ is a centered gaussian RV simply wrong?

Comment: You need to bound this difference for all $t\in [0,1]$ simultaneously.

Comment: So also a sum over the $2^n$ intervals of integral of the density of this centered gaussian on each interval wouldn't work?

Comment: I appreciate your way, I just find that estimate on the brownian bridge quite the trick for this question, I am a bit surprised there's not a more "hands on" approach, so to speak

Comment: Your approach doesn't work - see the discussion in the comment to my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980898/finding-mathbbp-max-t-leq-1-w-tt-geq-1).